# how to detect if browsers support custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I'm looking at modernizr which is supposed to help with feature detection which is supposedly the bees knees in figuring out if your website is compatible with a given web browser but I do not see anything that indicates that I can use it to detect custom HTML elements that we create & define in our content.

If it's not modernizr, how do I reliably detect whether a browser is capable of handling custom HTML elements the "HTML 5" way?

Comment: You really don't have to. If you include the code that makes old versions of IE work properly, then your non-standard elements will work on all modern browsers. It's a questionable practice, however, to do that anyway.

Comment: Let me clarify - the intention is to **not** support old versions and notify users that they need to upgrade the browsers. We have no intention of supporting older browsers.

Comment: Ah. Well I'm not sure how you'd check for that; there are probably different things that happen in different old browsers when an unknown tag is encountered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modernizr doesn't have a test for this at the moment, however since it has an API to create the element, it should be as simple as

```
var supportsCustomElements = ('registerElement' in document)
```

to detect for v0 of the API. To check for the more up to date v1, its

```
var supportsCustomElements = ('customElements' in window)
```

([more info on the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in))

Comment: Just to clarify - Since registerElement is a HTML5 thing, I actually don't need to have modernizr in order to test using the code you provided, right?

Comment: Totally! You actually don't need anything to run what I have used, it can literally run in any javascript engine.  I updated the answer for more info on the `in` operator.

Comment: Awesome! However, it doesn't seem to be the right solution because IE 9+ does not have registerElement defined on the document even though it does indeed render custom elements as expected. How bizarre. For now, I have a workaround -- I use `"register" in xtag` and use Mozilla's x-tag library which does give the correct answers (so far). Maybe we'll find a better solution than that?

Comment: do you mean custom tags or custom elements? Custom Elements (http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) is definitely  not supported in IE 9 http://caniuse.com/#search=custom elements

Comment: Ah, I did not realize there is a difference between custom tags and custom elements. Now I'm unsure if what I'm wanting is actually tags so let's elaborate -- all I want to do is be able to do `<my-own-tag class="foo bar">...</my-own-tag>` --- I didn't really need what x-tag library (nor polymer library) offers as they add lifecycle events when registering a custom elements which I have no need at the present for. When I tested, I found it to work on IE 9+ and others. The odd thing is that Mozilla's x-tag library claims it can work on IE 9+. I assume they do polyfilling for custom elements?

Comment: yes, you can polyfill custom elements. if you just want to create `<my-awesome-element>` and don't need anything else, it will work everywhere with the htmlshiv

Comment: Ooo, nice! I'll look at it. But back to the question at the hand -- would my workaround mentioned be the best possible solution or are there better ones?

Comment: there really isn't a need to test anything. it just works with the shiv. but if you _needed_ to for some reason, something like `document.createElement('my-awesome-element').nodeName === "MY-AWESOME-ELEMENT"` would technically do it.

Comment: A quick followup -- I found out that the `"register" in xtag` will generate false positive results whereas Patrick's `createElement` test is more accurate for determining whether a browser is capable of handling custom tags (which is what I was actually after even though my original question was for custom elements).

Comment: did not work for me. i am using iphone 7, 11.03. please remove or change this comment. It is not true. Safari browsers support custom elements and your statement above returns false..

Comment: @user1709076 this comment is many years old, and the API has changed. Updated with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but just wanted to say that Modernizer is supporting it now.