# Test support for customized built-in elements

Tags: javascript, web-component

Is there a way to test support for customized built-in elements vs. autonomous custom elements? The way to test for support for v1 of WebComponents with `(‘customElements’ in window)` [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097501/7197027), but I haven’t found anything which could help on identifying more detailed support on CustomElements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to detect if browsers support custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096743/how-to-detect-if-browsers-support-custom-elements)

Comment: @StefanN: This question is more detailed about what _kind_ of custom elements the browser supports, customized built-in elements or autonomous custom elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a customized built-in element and check the `name` property of its `constructor`:

```js
customElements.define('test-el', class TestEl extends HTMLDivElement {}, { extends: 'div' })
let supportsCBI = document.createElement('div', {is: 'test-el'}).constructor.name === 'TestEl'
console.log(supportsCBI)
```

Answer (score 2):

To test the feature, you could:

1. Define a customized built-in element.
2. Try to create it.
3. See if it throw an exception.

Example:

```
var CustomBuiltinSupport = false
try {
    class FakeButton extends HTMLButtonElement {}
    customElements.define( 'fake-button', FakeButton, { extends: 'button' } )
    new FakeButton
    CustomBuiltinSupport = true
} 
catch ( e ) {
    console.log( e )
}
console.info( 'Custom Builtin Element Support: ', CustomBuiltinSupport )
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a completely valid answer but the previous one is easier to compact into a test function for a project.

Comment: @droid001 Note that the other answer will generate an exception in some old browsers so you should use try/catch to avoid an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the property `extends` is read:

```
let supportCustomizedBuiltInElements = false

customElements.define('some-element', SomeElement, { 
    get extends () { 
        supportCustomizedBuiltInElements = true
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think checking if the `createElement`'s options argument is used or not is enough. This has the advantage that it doesn't really define an unnecessary custom element in the CustomElement Registry.

```js
    let supports = false;
    document.createElement('div', {
      get is() {
        supports = true; 
      }
    });
```